Revisiting Nietzsche and Scheler's Philosophies of Ressentiment
One often hears Nietzsche's views on ressentiment cited, but I contend that they are resentful. Nietzsche considered ressentiment as a central theme of his philosophy describing it as feelings of powerlessness and envy. It is also accompanied by a deep-seated resentment against those who possess power. Ressentiment, in the Nietzschean sense, is closely tied to the "slave morality" of Christian ethics. Instead of being life-affirming, this ethics is life-denying and stifles individuality, authenticity, and creative self-expression. It is reactionary, morally undermining the "strong" through moral judgments and guilt. Nietzsche views ressentiment as a destructive force hindering cultural flourishing without exception. This is why he advocated the revaluation of values.
But Max Scheler, despite being heavily influenced by Nietzsche, explored the concept of ressentiment and offered a significantly different approach. He first emphasized the importance of empathy or the ability to understand the feelings of others. Ressentiment, Scheler claims, arises from the inability to empathize with people possessing power and privilege. Scheler, therefore, did not see ressentiment as inherently negative and destructive. He argued that it could serve as a catalyst for social change and justice. He argued that ressentiment can lead to both destructive and transformative outcomes for the individual. It depends on how one channeled the emotions and whether he or she sought positive or perpetuated negativity.
While Nietzsche portrayed ressentiment as a destructive force, Scheler offered a more complex perspective, acknowledging its potential for both harm and transformational change. Which of the two has the "stronger," more advantageous interpretation and why?

"Stronger" and more advantageous according to whom?

I think Lou Salomé.

In which text does Scheler say that ressentiment arises from a lack of empathy for the powerful, and can be a force for good? From what I understand of Scheler, he rejects a positive role for hatred and the value-inversion that ressentiment brings.

@Hokon here is the book: https://www.marquette.edu/mupress/Ressentiment.shtml I take Scheler to be arguing that the recognition of ressentiment as a possibility to turn negative emotions into positive ones. This is how one avoids the "poisoning of the mind," Scheler warns against.

Thanks. I guess I need to re-read my copy of that, since I have no memory of this. I'll get back to you later.

Cool! Thanks for reaching out. I would enjoy to hear you response.

You know, it's kinda wild how both Nietzsche and Scheler go deep on this whole ressentiment thing, but end up with totally different vibes. Like, Nietzsche's all doom and gloom – ressentiment is this big bad monster that's gonna wreck everything. Scheler's a bit more chill, saying it can be, like, a tool for good, even if it's messy.
Honestly, I think Scheler kinda wins this round. Nietzsche's take feels a little too black and white. Yeah, getting stuck in a bitter, resentful hole sucks, but saying it always leads to destruction feels simplistic. People are more complicated than that!
Scheler gets that ressentiment comes from a place of pain – feeling powerless, like you're getting screwed over. And that pain can be fuel for change! Think about social movements, revolutions – people rising up against injustice. That takes serious guts, and yeah, maybe some anger and resentment too. But it can lead to a better world!
So, yeah, it's not about saying ressentiment is "good" or "bad". It's about recognizing its power and figuring out how to use it constructively, for positive change.

I'd like to see how you fit incels into this "good ressentment" and still be consistent.

@Miss_Understands Individual ressentiment appears to translate to pathological narcissism in modern theory, so for recovery we have for example, on page 89-90 : "Chasseguet-Smirgel sees all life as about man’s attempt to redeem this promise [of perfection and wholeness] by realizing a reconciliation between the ego and the ego ideal. This reconciliation may take two forms: one progressive, one regressive. Progressive reconciliation involves the hope that through postponement and

hard work one may eventually achieve a level of mastery over self and world that approximates what the ego ideal desires— namely, the wholeness and perfection associated with the state of primary narcissism. Chasseguet-Smirgel expressly notes the similarity between her concept of progressive reconciliation with the ego ideal and Grunberger’s concept of object mastery, which acts in a similar fashion to help heal the narcissistic wound. [Ego Ideal, p. 44.] In progressive reconciliation the ego ideal becomes closely allied with the superego. Regressive reconciliation, on the other hand, seeks

immediate, complete reconciliation, often via attempts at fusion with powers greater than the self." So the recovery generally involves addressing the elements of bad narcissism (envy, etc.) and turning them into good narcissism (mastery & competence). The idea doesn't translate back so well, i.e. turning bad resentment into good resentment.
